# PARSE JSON and Store into SQLite

Tags: node.js, sqlite

API endpoint: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/younginnovations/internship-challenges/master/programming/petroleum-report/data.json

I want to fetch data from the above API endpoint and store all the data into SQLite.
I have configured Sqlite in my express project.

my server.js file is :

```
const express = require('express')
const https = require('https');
const bodyparser = require('body-parser')
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
const { json } = require('body-parser');
const { response } = require('express');
var db = require("./database.js")
const apiurl = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/younginnovations/internship-challenges/master/programming/petroleum-report/data.json"

//using node fetch
fetch(apiurl)
        .then(resp => resp.json())
        .then((resp) => console.log(resp))




app.post("/api/user", (req, res, next) =>{
    var data = {
        year : req.body.year,
        name : req.body.petroleum_product,
        price : req.body.sale,
        country : req.body.country

    }
    var sql = 'INSERT INTO PRODUCT(name, price, year, country) VALUES (?,?,?,?)'
    var params = [data.year, data.name, data.price, data.country]
    db.run(sql, params, function(err, result){
        if(err){
            res.status(400).json({"error": err.message})
        }
        res.json({
            "message" : "success",
            "data" : data,

        })
    })
})




app.get("/api/product", (req, res, next)=>{
    var sql = "select *from PRODUCT"
    var params = []
    db.all(sql, params ,(err, rows)=>{
        if(err){
            res.status(400).json({"error":err.message})
            return;
        }
        res.json({
            "message" : "success",
            "data" : rows
        })
    })
})
         
         
app.get("/", function(req, res){
     res.send("HELLO")
    })

    const Port = process.env.PORT || 3000

app.listen(Port, console.log('Server Running in ${process.env.NODE_ENV} mode on port ${}PORT'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, it is quite a complex question, so I will give a short explanation in steps.

1. You need to create tables for data you want to store if have not done yet.
2. You need to fetch the actual data. You have code for that already.

   ```
   fetch(apiurl)
       .then(resp => resp.json());
   ```
3. Now in the similar way you are using the `db.run` you need to iterate over the response data and insert it into a table you want to insert. e.g.

   ```
    fetch(apiurl)
       .then(resp => resp.json());
       .then((body) => {
            for (const entry of body) {
               db.run('INSERT ... bla-bla-bla', [entry.year, ...], function (err) { // add handling here });
            }
       });
   ```

Best regards.

Comment: Its says the body is not iterable.

Comment: Well, maybe the response format is different. I was writing the code off the top of my head. Check the response format.

Comment: The data i want on my database is here,,https://raw.githubusercontent.com/younginnovations/internship-challenges/master/programming/petroleum-report/data.json    .Can you please give me some more ideas.

Comment: The idea is to put a `debugger;` in the `then` statement and debug the code to see what you actually get when you download the file. Then align your code with what you see.